# SQL select query not show result with where in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I'm sorry if it's a ridiculous question, but I don't know what to do with it.

when I run this query:

```
SELECT fields.name
FROM
  fields
WHERE
  fields.inf = "Emergency طوارئ"
```

no result show up even if i put 'name' instead of 'inf' in where, but it work if I put the 'id'.

This is a sample from table fields:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | name                                 | inf               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | Education التعليم                    | Emergency طوارئ   |
| 2  | Health and Nutrition الصحة و التغذية | Emergency طوارئ   |
| 3  | Human Rights حقوق الانسان             | Development تطوير |
| 4  | Special Needs الاحتياجات الخاصة       | Development تطوير |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Please add the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command on your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but it's maybe because of the character "طوارئ".
Try fields.inf like "Emergency%" if it's enough for you

That will select every row with a inf which start with "Emergency"

Sorry for my english, i hope i help you